# WP E-Commerce creating categories programmaticaly

Tags: categories, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I was searching WP Ecommerce documentation, trying to find what function to use to add category to WPEC, but no luck. Is there some function or piece of code that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`wp_insert_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) to add terms to the `wpsc_product_category` taxonomy:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'description'=> 'term description.',
    'slug' => 'my-term'
);
wp_insert_term( 'My term', 'wpsc_product_category', $args );
?>
```

Comment: Yep, thats it, tnx a lot.